# Select comparação dias com data atual não funciona

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho este `select` que trás os dados da seguinte forma, se `DataCobranca` for 10, e hoje for o dia 05, ele vai buscar todos os clientes que for dia 10, pois vai ser gerado 5 dias antes, ou caso `DiaEspecificoMarcar` for `true` e `DiaEspecifico` for igual o dia de hoje, ele também vai aparecer neste `select`

```
var contrato = db
    .Contrato
    .Include(a => a.PedidoVenda)
    .Include(a => a.Cliente)
    .Where(a => a.PedidoVenda.EmpresaID == model.EmpresaID && 
                a.Cancelado == false && 
                DateTime.Parse(a.PrimeiraCobranca.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) >= DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) &&
                a.DiaEspecificoMarcar == true && a.DiaEspecifico == int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"))) ||
                (a.DiaEspecificoMarcar == false && (int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota) == int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")))
    ).ToList();
```

Só que quando o `DataCobranca` for 05, ele precisa ser gerado 5 dias antes, ou quanto estiver no parâmetro, então como estou usando data retroativa, no dia 31/03 e no dia 01/04, onde deveria puxar os do dia 05, mas ele sempre puxa zerado.

Na verdade, porque a `DataCobranca = 5`, e o `DataProcessamentoNota = 5`, como ele faz a conta, ele verifica 5-5 = 0, no caso ele deveria pegar o último dia do mês, ou então outro caso, se `DataProcessamentoNota = 10` ele deveria fazer a conta 5 - 10, e então seria -5. Sendo que o resultado deveria ser 10 dias antes. Como calcular como dias mesmo. Como posso verificar?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(a.PrimeiraCobranca.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))`, que parse maluco é esse? a primeiraCobranca não é um datetime? tipo e também o que faz isso nada? Veja tem problemas no seu código

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu preciso de verificar se a data da primeira cobrança é maior ou igual ao dia que está sendo gerado. é sim, estou pegando somente a date, e não as horas.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic até então quando não fica negativo funciona, eu preciso fazer a parte do `int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota` que é  a que está dando problema quando gera um negativo, pois está sendo tratado como `int` e não `DateTime`

Comment: Mariana a.PrimeiraCobranca é do tipo `DateTime`? Qual é a versão do `EntityFramework`? se for não é assim que se faz !

Comment: Sim, é do tipo `DateTime`, a versão do EntityFrameworkCore é `2.1.4`

Comment: suas conversões estão todas erradas! esse é o problema também, e outro assunto gera conversões a nivel do cliente é ruim essa pesquisa.

Comment: Aqui você precisa pegar o dia? `a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)` ???? o correto é `a.DataCobranca.Day` internamente ele faz a conversão.

Comment: No caso a `DataCobranca` é do tipo string, ela salva o T05, T10, etc, por isso utilizo o `Substring` para pegar os dois números.

Comment: onde você fez isso: `DateTime.Parse(a.PrimeiraCobranca.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))` é só isso `a.PrimeiraCobranca.Date`.

Comment: `int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"))` é só `DateTime.Now.Day`

Comment: então esse pode ficar como está! `DataCobranca`

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica! faz um pesquisa somente com o tipo 10  e depois faz uma só com o tipo 5, restringe dessa forma. Se precisa juntar essas duas no final é fácil, mas, do jeito que está muito confuso entender até a sua pergunta ... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic mas até então não resolve o meu problema, já que o problema está aqui `int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota`, o que me passou melhora o código, mas não resolve o problema.

Comment: A melhoria do código foi bom para você ver o caminho errado que estava tendo, mas, ai nessa linha `int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota` tem outro problema, mas, diz ai qual é o problema dessa linha?

Comment: O problema é data, ele está comparando a `DataCobranca = T10` com a `DataProcessamentoNota = 5`, ou seja pegando o `Substring` 10 - 5 = 5 ele saberia que para gerar a nota no dia 5, agora quando é menor, por exemplo `DataCobranca = T05` e `DataProcessamentoNota = 05` 05-05 ele daria 0, ou 05-10 = -5, que ele vai comparar com o dia atual, para ver se é o dia correto, no caso 05-05, ele deveria gerar no ultimo dia do mes anterior, e 05-10, ele deveria gerar no dia 26. Não sei se deu pra entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser feito desta forma

```
var contrato = db
.Contrato
.Include(a => a.PedidoVenda)
.Include(a => a.Cliente)
.Where(a => a.PedidoVenda.EmpresaID == model.EmpresaID && 
            a.Cancelado == false && 
            DateTime.Parse(a.PrimeiraCobranca.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) >= DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) &&
            a.DiaEspecificoMarcar == true && a.DiaEspecifico == int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"))) ||
            (a.DiaEspecificoMarcar == false && ((int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) 
    - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota)<=0?DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) 
    - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota).Day:int.Parse(a.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)) - a.PedidoVenda.Empresa.DataProcessamentoNota) == int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")))
).ToList();
```